# Cant interact with iframe after switching to it Python/Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, button, xpath, iframe

I'm trying to interact with a button on a page with the following structure. The button of interest is within a div in the body of an iframe, which is inside the main body. I've already read all the stackoverflow questions about how to switch to an iframe - as you can see below I have no issue with that. What I have an issue with is that regardless of that advice I am unable to interact with the iframe I switched to.

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="someApp" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html">
    <head>
        <script>a lot of scripts</script>
    </head>
    <body class="unwantedBody">
        <iframe> some iframes</iframe>
        <div> different divs </div>
        <main> 
            some content
            <iframe> multiple iframes on different nested levels </iframe>
        </main>
        <div> more divs </div>
        <script> more scripts </script>
        <div id='interesting div'>
            <iframe src="uniqueString">
                <!doctype html>
                #document
                <html>
                    <body>
                        <div>
                            <button id='bestButton'>
                                'Nice title'
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </body>
                </html>
            </iframe>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Using Jupyter Notebook I've been able to locate the iframe and switch to it. The problem is not related to trying to interact with the iFrame too fast, because I control the speed. I've tried using Expected conditions and waiting until the iframe can be switched to, but it is irrelevant to my problem.

```
driver.switch_to.default_content # Making sure no other frame is selected
iframe = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//iframe[contains(@src, 'uniqueString')]")
driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)
print(iframe.get_attribute('id'))
```

The above code prints out "interesting div", so it successfully finds the div where the iframe is and apparently selects the div? Then I try to parse the iframe like this:

```
bestButton = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@id = 'bestButton']")
bestButton.click()
```

This gives the error:

> Message: element not interactable

I also tried to interact with the body within the iframe **after switching to it** with the above switch_to.frame(iframe), so in this example driver is already at the iframe:

```
document = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//html/body')
info = document.get_attribute('class')
print(info)
```

This prints out

> unwantedBody

So somehow the driver has not switched to the iFrame I specified, and instead is still stuck on the main HTML. When loading the webpage on chrome I can find the button I want with just this xpath //button[contains(@id='bestButton')] but in Selenium it doesn't work, because it is split by the #document within the iframe.

What am I missing? If it helps, the iFrame I am interested in is actually a modal window about cookie consent, which I am trying to get rid of to interact with the site.